# Android. Rotate animation in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-animation

I have a class which extends Fragment, I want to make rotation of ImageView  when onCreateView() called.

Here is my code:

rotator.xml - set animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Here I use my animation:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    Context context;

    private ImageView backButtonImage;
    private Animation rotation;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = container.getContext();


        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);

        backButtonImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.backButton);

        rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotator);
        backButtonImage.startAnimation(rotation);

        return root;
    }
```

But, when I run my app the image doesn't rotate. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem in your rotator.xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”"
```

You have an extra set of quotes which are invalid in an xml, it should be like this:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

But you don't even need to specify the xmlns:android property since you already did it on your root element, so the whole file can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate 
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Yes, it works.  That's my inattention :) By the way, it also works without onResume().